# How i can use "querySelectorAll"?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, queryselector

My html:

```
<label for="answer_1" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" id="answer_1">Answer</label>
<label for="answer_2" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" id="answer_2">Answer</label>
<label for="answer_3" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" id="answer_3">Answer</label>
```

My JS:

```
var answers = ["Answer_1","Answer_2","Answer_3"];
var answer_labels = document.querySelectorAll(".answer_label");
for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
    answer_labels[i].innerText = answers[i]
}
```

When I want to set text to my labels, I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')

Comment: The described behaviour will occur when the shown script is executed when less than three elements with the class `answer_label` exist in the DOM, so I guess you have your script in the `head` of your HTML document (or at least before your `<label>` elements)?

Comment: i have script in  end of my code

Comment: @nyar When iterating an array, and referring to a member in another array (or a NodeList in this particular case) with an index of the iterated array, you've to check that the member exists in that other array for the situations the arrays don't have the same length.

Comment: @nyar the problem is that the code shown would not result in the given error if your script is executed after the `<label>` elements are in the DOM, and if the counts match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was that I did not specify "`<!DOCTYPE html>"` in html file...

Comment: This answer doesn't fix the past of index issue in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the for loop.

change `for (var i = 0; i < .length; i++)`

to  `for (var i = 0; i < answer_labels.length; i++)`

```js
var answers = ["Answer_1","Answer_2","Answer_3"]
var answer_labels = document.querySelectorAll(".answer_label");
for (var i = 0; i < answer_labels.length; i++){
    answer_labels[i].innerText = answers[i];
}
```

```html
  <label for="answer_1" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_1">Answer</label>
        <label for="answer_2" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_2">Answer</label>
        <label for="answer_3" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_3">Answer</label>
```

Comment: The question is about `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')` so if the OP fixes the problem in their setup, it will likely still not work as expected. I would suspect that the text remains `Answer` now.

Comment: @t.niese Notice, that Ran iterates the NodeList, not the text array (`answers`). But this can still fire the same error, if there's more elements in the document than `answers` has members.

Comment: @Teemu I agree with that. But if the shown code reflects what the OP has then the counts match. So the explanation would be that the script is executed before the elements are in the DOM. But I agree that the OP might have something else in the actual code than shown.

Comment: Forloop aside... run `answer_labels[0].innterText = answers[0];` and see if this will work. The loop is not the problem because even if the values were hardcoded, the program won't show desired results with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the labels without destroying the radio button inputs inside you should maybe do something like this:

```js
var answers = ["Answer_1","Answer_2","Answer_3"]
document.querySelectorAll(".answer_label").forEach((l,i)=>{
  l.innerHTML=l.querySelector("input").outerHTML+answers[i];
})
```

```html
<label for="answer_1" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_1">Answer</label>
<label for="answer_2" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_2">Answer</label>
<label for="answer_3" class="answer_label"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="answer_3">Answer</label>
```